# hover on image displays text next to the image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text next to  the image when the cursor is over the image. i found many codes that display the text OVER the image but Can somebody give me a code for doing that ? 
i tried this code but it displays the text above the image

```
<i><div class='element7' style='position: absolute; right:-250px; bottom: 400px; z-      index: 4;'>
<img src='".$donnees[1]."' height='100' width='170' /></td><p style='bottom :  300px;right : 300px;'>some text : image 1 </p></i>

<style type="text/css"> 

.element7 {
width: 730px;
height: 133px;
line-height: 0px;
color: transparent;
font-size: 50px;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue",     Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 200;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.element7 :hover {
line-height: -20px;
color: #fff;
top:100px;
left:100px;

}

.element7 img{
float: right;
margin: 0 50px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: first try something of your own.

Comment: Or you could add a tiptip style of hover text that uses the title attribute.
But what have you tried ?

Comment: i tried something , ( a text displayed over the image ) and tried to separate the text and display it next to the image but it didn't work

Comment: Please show a demo that we can see in action, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you make your `html` but [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KdVaj/1/) works, its just simple css. if your html is more complex you can do this with jquery.

You make a hover on the container and showing the text like that.

```
<div id="contain">
    <div class="fake-image"></div>
    <div class="text">some text</div>
</div>​

#contain{
    clear: both;
}

.fake-image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contain:hover div.text{
    display: block;
}

.text{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left; 
    display: none;    
}​
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your html that you provided makes no sense at all because you got a `</td>` but no start tag, if this is a part of a table its better you should post the full html of it.